# Fallo en pine script

Tags: codificación, pine-script

Tengo un problema con mi estrategia en `pinescript`, a la hora de ver el `backtest` la estrategia únicamente abre las operaciones que le dan la gana, aún cumpliendose las condiciones que marco a la estrategia solo abre algunas operaciones y no todas, ¿Alguien sabe el porque pasa esto?

```
//@version=5

strategy('Mi estrategia', overlay=true)

// Variables de entrada

wmaLength = input.int(14)

rsi_length = input.int(14)

// Calcular la WMA y el RSI

wma = ta.wma(close, wmaLength)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)

rsi_S= ta.crossunder(rsi,70)

rsi_L = ta.crossover(rsi,30)

// Generar señales de compra y venta if close > wma and rsi_L

strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
if close < wma and rsi_S

strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)
pine-script
```

Answer (score 0):

- Aunque no lo aclaras, este codigo fué generado por chatGPT. Quizas no lo sepas, pero no esta permitido este tipo de preguntas
  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned
- Tu codigo no compila. Entonces es raro que digas "la estrategia únicamente abre las operaciones que le dan la gana"
- El "if" debe estar indentado por espacios o tabulacion
  https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Conditional_structures.html#introduction

El codigo con la indectacion corregida te queda así:

```
//@version=5

strategy('Mi estrategia', overlay=true)
// Variables de entrada
wmaLength = input.int(14)
rsi_length = input.int(14)
// Calcular la WMA y el RSI
wma = ta.wma(close, wmaLength)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)
rsi_S= ta.crossunder(rsi,70)
rsi_L = ta.crossover(rsi,30)
// Generar señales de compra y venta 
if close > wma and rsi_L
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
if close < wma and rsi_S
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)
```

- No le veo nada raro. Cuando el precio es mayor a WMA y el RSI cruza 30, tenes señal de compra, y viceversa.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El if fue fallo a la hora de escribir el codigo aqui, en trading view le tenia bien puesto, gracias por la ayuda y un saludo.

Comment: Podrias explicarme porque piensas que no esta permitido este tipo de preguntas? nunca dijiomos nada de preguntas hechas en base a codigo generado por una herramienta IA... en realidad, si OP tiene un problema con codigo, la pregunta es valida... Si el codigo no sirve, entonces hay que aclararselo...

Comment: De paso, la misma publicacion en ingles, esta en nuestro sitio en meta ;)